# How to use ECMAScript-6 import from a GWT jsni code?

Tags: ecmascript-6, gwt

So, I know that in GWT I can write JSNI code that is purely javascript code.
But, unfortunately JSNI code does not compile if I use ES6 code within it.

That means that, for example, I cannot do stuff like this:

```
private native void jsniMethod(String jsModule) /*-{
    import(jsModule)
        .then(loadedModule => {
            doStuffWithLoadedModule(loadedModule);
        })
        .catch(err => alert(err));
}-*/;
```

Is there a way to achieve this in GWT code?
I mean, I need a reference to a loadedModule so I can use it in some jsni code (the doStuffWithLoadedModule method implementation).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cannot be done. You need to put JS features that are not supported from JSNI into some kind of external JS, or rewrite them in older JS which is compatible with JSNI. Consider ScriptInjector as one option for this, or your host html page.

For this specific thing, you just need to replace the arrow operator with a function:

```java
private native void jsniMethod(String jsModule) /*-{
    import(jsModule)
        .then(function(loadedModule) {
            doStuffWithLoadedModule(loadedModule);
        })
        .catch(function(err) { alert(err) });
}-*/;
```

---

As an alternative, to use java lambdas, you can use JsInterop. Keep in mind that `import` isn't actually a function call, but a js keyword, though this should still work:

```java
@JsMethod(namespace = "<window>")
public native Promise<Object> import(String jsModuleName);
```

Then, you can invoke this and pass in Java lambdas:

```java
private void notJsniMethod(String jsModule) {
    import(jsModule)
        .then(loadedModule -> {
            doStuffWithLoadedModule(loadedModule);
            return null;
        })
        .catch_(err -> {
            DomGlobal.alert(err.toString())
            return null;
        });

}
```

Changes from the original JS/JSNI:

- `=>` is replaced with java's `->`, which operates nearly the same way
- `alert(...)` is now `DomGlobal.alert(...)`, since java doesn't have a "global" namespace
- explicit `return null` is required, since java doesn't let you just "forget" to return a value when a value is required.
- `.catch(...)` is replaced with `.catch_(...)`, since Java doesn't permit a keyword to be used as an identifier

Comment: Is there any reference available on which version of Javascript / ECMAScript is compatible with GWT JSNI?

Comment: @AttilaCsipak the answer is that it is a very limited set of ES3, minus the `with` keyword, plus some custom syntax for referencing Java types and members. https://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html is a good reference. As in the answer, avoid JSNI, anything JSNI can do, jsinterop can do better and more maintainably.

Comment: While I tend to trust your word on this topic (especially since you have a track record on SO with GWT), the linked official JSNI guide does not state anything about ES version compatibility. Perhaps someone with intimate knowledge of the GWT compiler could point out some hard evidence about this in the source code, but it's not very transparent to omit this piece of information from the official documentation. Your comment is still worth an upvote. My disappointment is pointed towards the general direction of the GWT project.

Comment: I'm on the GWT steering committee, and one of the main contributors at this time, you can confirm this at gwtproject.org and the github project. JSNI is very out of date, so it isn't being updated to support new ES versions - I don't think it was even common to call it "ES3" at the time that JSNI was created. GWT can only emit ES3 output as well (no classes, modules, async/await). If you have a GWT codebase that has dropped its JSNI in favor of the more modern JsInterop, your project may already be compatible with J2CL as a future compiler. Chat with us more at https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt